# How are overhanging elements supported in buildings?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, masonry

I wonder how overhanging elements, like those shown on images below, are made structurally sound. I assume that one can approximate the structure as a cantilever beam, which means that some parts of the structure will be under tensional stress. From what I know, building materials like masonry cannot handle tension well.

My question therefore is how are such structures made stable. Is there some reinforcing material included? An analysis of the stresses in the structure would be helpful.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Notice those gussets at the bottom?

Comment: There are lots of ways.  I've seen entire houses hanging off cliff edges, held in place with cables securely anchored in a manner similar to suspension bridges.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to open space balconies, the structures in the photos are supported on structural framing that is cantilevered out from the main building skeleton, which provides the stabilizing forces necessary to hold the overhanging structure in position.

[image][image][image]

[image]

[Balcony Design](https://csengineermag.com/balcony-design/)

Comment: Could you add more detail about how this is done in practice or include some references to look at, please?

Comment: @FusRoDah a single example is sufficient of a beam or support sticking out, held in place by a mass inboard.